# OCI renewal for a minor

Tags: india

My son has a OCI card which will soon expire, I would like to know if I can apply for a regular visa instead of renewal of OCI as he has a upcoming visit soon to India.

Comment: Why don't you renew the OCI before the visit?

Comment: The OCI procedure is very daunting and it I don't know how long it will take them to process the renewal

Comment: I admit I didn't look too closely, but it did not seem like a difficult process when I read the directions. It seemed that you could just fill in the application online and then send the documents to your nearest consulate of India. The FAQ says that they are normally processed within 30 days.